# Enable smart indent on curly braces

Tags: go, vim, terminal, neovim, auto-indent

I have to do this every time when I open curly braces

[image]

vim config for indent:

```
"" Fix backspace indent
set backspace=indent,eol,start

"" Tabs. May be overridden by autocmd rules
set autoindent
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set smarttab
```

What to do?

Comment: The most simple way which is just mapping for the keypresses you could use to achieve the same: ```inoremap {<Enter> {<Enter>}<Esc>O```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [amix/vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc), a powerful vim configuration.

I have installed the awesome version and it could implement what you want. Moreover, it has lots of useful configurations that could improve your efficiency.

If you write go, you could install [fatih/vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go), a powerful plugin adds go language support for Vim.

Comment: I have everything you mentioned, except that feature I have mentioned.

Comment: @SaiKrishna Could you paste your `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 0):

[delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) does the thing. Set option `delimitMate_expand_cr` to 1 or 2 in your `.vimrc`:

```
let delimitMate_expand_cr = 2
```

See:

```
:h delimitMate_expand_cr
:h delimitMateExpansion
```

Also you can use simple mapping on `{{` to do same:

```
inoremap {{ <C-o>o{<CR>}<C-o>O
```